# Android/Google: it possible to add a free annual subscription promo/offer for more than 90 days?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console, in-app-subscription

We have a group of small users, our ambassadors, whom we are offering a free annual subscription.  on iOS this is no problem.  On Android/Google, however, it seems there is a limit of 90 days?

Here is what I see when trying to create a Promo, for an annual, 365 days:

> Free trial duration must be between 3 and 90 days

[image]